# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in whatsapp api with php 5.3

Tags: php

My script is working really fine on my xampp php version 5.6. Now I tried to upload it on the server php version 5.3.3 , it says

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '['
```

The line which its mocking about is this one:

```
$this->pending_nodes[$number] = [];
```

The whole code block looks like this:

```
public function addPendingNode(ProtocolNode $node){
  $from = $node->getAttribute("from");
  if(strpos($from,Constants::WHATSAPP_SERVER) !== false)
    $number = ExtractNumber($node->getAttribute("from"));
  else
    $number = ExtractNumber($node->getAttribute("participant"));

  if(!isset($this->pending_nodes[$number]))
    $this->pending_nodes[$number] = [];

  $this->pending_nodes[$number][] = $node;
}
```

I am thankful for any help, I cannot seach [ with google and have no idea where it could come from, since on xampp its working fine.

Comment: for 5.3 try this $this->pending_nodes['.$number.'] = [];

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo what you suggested would cause a parse error.

Comment: @tontonlayxx I would suggest upgrading php to 5.6 - Given 5.3 and 5.4 are unsupported; 5.5 is deprecated: [Supported Versions](http://php.net/supported-versions.php)

Comment: I am also to upgrade my server php version @ash

Comment: **thinking to upgrade*** @ash

Answer (score 2):

[Short Array syntax was introduced in PHP 5.4 only](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php).

Change

```
$this->pending_nodes[$number] = [];
```

to

```
$this->pending_nodes[$number] = array();
```

or [upgrade to a PHP version that is not End of Life](http://php.net/supported-versions.php).